# ForEach doubled the view creation

Tags: swiftui

This is the code. Every time DetailView is created we assign it an id. Unexpectedly, the detailView is created 6 times. What happened here?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
       List {
            ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { _ in
                DetailView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    static var count = 0
    var id: Int
    
    init() {
        id = Self.count
        print("Init the Detail View - \(id).")
        Self.count += 1
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello \(id)")
    }
}
```

From the console.

> Init the Detail View - 0.
> Init the Detail View - 1.
> Init the Detail View - 2.
> Init the Detail View - 3.
> Init the Detail View - 4.
> Init the Detail View - 5.

From the screen:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of passing the id value from ForEach to DetailView?

Comment: SwiftUI can call the `init` as many times as it wants

Comment: try `id = self.id` in `init`

Comment: Views are structs, value types like ints. Don't worry about being init many times it's negligible memory. Don't do anything in init though because body is called when the lets, state and binding vars change. If you do things in init you'll mess that up.

Comment: I believe this is SwiftUI's internal approach for initiating views wrapped by it. If you print, you see that for each of the elements in 0..<2 it is executing the block twice. But in the UI output you see 3 cells as you expect. So I don't think it is anything to care about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance of a View in SwiftUI may be recreated over and over again during its life cycle. The mechanism is a dependency graph under the hood. You can take a look at [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) for more details. For example, `DetailView` will initialize with a simple presented sheet, that is not related to `List`.

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { id in
                DetailView()
            }
        }

        Button {
            presented = true
        } label: {
            Text("Present sheet")
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $presented) {
        Text("Sheet")
    }
}
```

```
Init the Detail View - 0.
Init the Detail View - 1.
Init the Detail View - 0.
Init the Detail View - 1.
```

It's not the right way to handle View state like above because `static var count` is available during the App lifetime and `var count` is available during the View lifetime.

In this case, the DetailView is a `static` view with an ID from outside, not a `dynamic` view with data-binding so you just need to pass the ID as an initial parameter, remove the static variable one and let SwiftUI does the job (recall the `body` computed property if the dependency changes).

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        ...
    }
}
```